# Error while indexing data in Elasticsearch using R

Tags: r, elasticsearch

I am trying to upload data to Elasticsearch using R. The data is stored as data table in R.

I'm using elastic package for R and have followed the steps given in this tutorial: https://ropensci.org/tutorials/elastic_tutorial/. I'm getting the following error:

I'm using the below code to upload the data table:

```
docs_bulk(elasticon, dt.mergedDataset, index = dt.mergedDataset$job_code)
```

For which I'm getting the following error message:

```
Error in sprintf(metadata_fmt, action, index, type, counter) : 
  arguments cannot be recycled to the same length
```

For Reference, `traceback()` Output:

```
5: sprintf(metadata_fmt, action, index, type, counter)
4: make_bulk(x[data_chks[[i]], , drop = FALSE], index, type, id_chks[[i]], 
       es_ids)
3: docs_bulk(conn, make_bulk(x[data_chks[[i]], , drop = FALSE], 
       index, type, id_chks[[i]], es_ids), ...)
2: docs_bulk.data.frame(elasticon, dt.mergedDataset, index = dt.mergedDataset$job_code)
1: docs_bulk(elasticon, dt.mergedDataset, index = dt.mergedDataset$job_code)
```

Comment: `elastic` pkg maintainer here. if you can share a reproducible example that causes the same error, then I can be of more help.

Comment: My data table has around 150,000 rows. I think the issue might be related to its size. As the same error doesn't occur when I convert mtcars to data table format.

Comment: run `traceback()` after the error and put that above so I can see where the error may be happening.

Comment: @sckott I've added `traceback()` output in the question above. Please let me know if there is any solution.